# How to get data attributes and values as object in select options (using chosen plugin)

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I am using the chosen plugin ([here](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)) and I have a multiple select where I want to get the values returned as an object.

Here is the code:

```
<select class="chozen" id="entities" multiple>

   <option data-name="Joe Blow" data-id="3" data-age="27">Joe Blow</option>
   <option data-name="Trish Thompson" data-id="4" data-age="21">Trish Thompson </option>
   <option data-name="Sam Jones" data-id="5" data-age="43">Sam Jones</option>

</select>
```

I then have a button to get the selected values of this input as:

var vals = $("#entities").val();

And it returns an array of innerHTML selected values as:

```
["Joe Blow","Trish Thompson","Sam Jones"]
```

*(Note: if I set the "value" attribute, it will return the values as an array rather than the innerHTML)*

What I am trying to do is take the data attributes and put that into an object array as:

```
[
   {name:"Joe Blow",id:"3",age:"27"} ,
   ....
]
```

Does anybody have any suggestions? ....

I could not find anything on the chozen documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
        selectedAsJSON: function(){
            var result = [];
            $('option:selected', this).each(function(){
                result.push($(this).data());
            })
            return result;
        }
    });
```

Usage:

```
$('#entities').selectedAsJSON();
```

The output will be an array of objects, where each `data-` will be a property.

**Update:** important to notice that this will work with any regular `select` element, not just with *chosen*. Also, your `option` may have any `data-` attr, will work as well.

Comment: @choz well, we're adding an extension method to the global jQuery object. It could be called by any jQuery selector, which should result in an empty array. Not really a problem :)

Comment: Wow, power is simplicity. Will this out tomorrow. Tks! :)

Comment: @WalkerFarrow glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Using [$.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) you'll only get the values of an input / select, try out by using the [:selected](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) Selector to get the whole elements. My working sample:

https://jsfiddle.net/rj8j5v0j/

Code you've to implement:

```
// build an array
var data = [];
$("#entities option:selected").map(function(){
    // push each selected option as an object with name, id and age
    data.push({
        name: $(this).data('name'),
        id: $(this).data('id'),
        age: $(this).data('age')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
$(document).on( 'change' , ‘.myselect’ , function() {
    console.log( $('.myselect option:selected').data(‘value’) );
});
```

Basically, I got the selected option in the original `<select>`, and then I got the data-attribute of that element. Chosen gives you a cloned version of the `<select>`, so you have to get the original reference by querying the selector twice.

```js
$('select').chosen();

$(document).on('change', '#mySelect', function(e) {
  var r = $('#mySelect option:selected').data('customF');
  $("#result").html(r);
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.6.1/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.6.1/chosen.jquery.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-12">
  <select class="form-control" id="mySelect">
    <option value="value1" data-custom-f="Cool">Option 1</option>
    <option value="value2" data-custom-f="Awesome">Option 2</option>
  </select>
  <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/luisbajana/222qaucg/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything in plugin documentation either but you can use small jQuery function to achieve what you need:

```
function returnSelectAsArray($object){    
    var dataArray = [],
        $selectedOptions = $object.find('option').filter(':selected'),
        $option;

    $selectedOptions.each(function(){        
        $option = $(this);
        dataArray.push({
            name: $option.attr('data-name'),
            id: $option.attr('data-id'),
            age: $option.attr('data-age'),
        });
    });
    return dataArray;
}

$('#entities').on('change chosen:change', function(){    
    console.log(returnSelectAsArray($(this)));
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/op615gn6/1/)**